# Create child object using jQuery dialog/partial view

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, partial-views, jquery-dialog

I am using MVC 5/jquery 1.10.2 and jquery ui 1.11.3

For this example I have a Parent object with one child object.  On the Create View for the parent object I have an auto-complete text box from which the user selects one of the children.  If the child does not yet exist, there is a link for the user to click on that opens a jQuery dialog which contains a partial view.

The code I am using to do this is below:

```
$(function () {
    var dialog = $("#dialog-form").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        width: 500,
        height: 450,
        dialogClass: "dialogStyle",
        draggable: true,
        resizable: false,
        modal: true,
        hide: { effect: "fade", duration: 1000 },
        title: "New Donor",
        open: function () {
            $(this).closest(".ui-dialog")
            .find(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close")
            //.removeclass("ui-dialog-titlebar-close")
            .html("<span class='ui-button-icon-primary ui-icon ui-icon-closethick'></span><span class='ui-button-text'>close</span>");
        }
    });

    $("#new-donor").click(function () {
        $("#dialog-form").load("@Url.Action("MinCreate", "Donors")", function () {
            dialog.dialog("open")
        });
    });
});
```

Now, I have two problems:

1. When I successfully submit the partial view form, I want to close the dialog and return the newly created child details into the existing parent form.  I have no idea how to do this.
2. If the validation fails on the partial view on the server side, I want to obviously return the failure to the existing dialog.  Currently it will redirect to the partial view.

My partial view code is here:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label dia-col-md-2" })
            <div class="dia-col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

    // other data entry fields here...

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="dia-col-md-offset-2 dia-col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

and my Controller code is here:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> MinCreate([Bind(Include = "Id,Name,Email,AddressLine1,City,State,PostalCode,PrimaryPhone")] Donor donor)
{
    try
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Donors.Add(donor);
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return PartialView("_Create");
    }
    return PartialView("_Create", donor);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so it took me a few days of thinking through this problem, and I *think* scurrie may have been trying to point me in this direction.  Below is the solution I've come up with:

1. I had to initiate all of the JavaScript code from the parent View.
2. I used an Ajax form on the partial and used the dialog "Submit" button
   to call $.ajax and send my form data and defined a "success" event.
3. The success event checks the return value from the Controller and if
   I set retObject.success == true then it finds the values on the
   parent form and sets the Donor name and Id, and I close the jQuery
   dialog.
4. If retObject.success is null then I know that I've returned
   the Invalid ModelState so I set that return value to the dialog
   forms .html property using the jQuery selector.

I understand probably 95% of what's going on below, so there may be some unnecessary code.  If you see something that could be better, please let me know!

My Partial view (Donors/_Create.cshtml - notice there is no html submit button as I'm using the Submit button from the jQuery dialog command:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("MinCreate", "Donors", new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod = "Post", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace}, new { id = "DonorForm" })){
<div class="form-horizontal">
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label dia-col-md-2" })
        <div class="dia-col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @id = "DonorFormName", @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <More Form Fields... />
</div>
}
```

My Parent form (Items/Create.cshtml):

```
<script>
$(function () {
    $("#DonorName").autocomplete({
        source: '@Url.Action("Autocomplete")',
        select: function (event, ui) {
            $("#DonorId").val(ui.item.value);
            $("#DonorName").val(ui.item.label);
            return false;
        },
        focus: function (event, ui)
        {
            $("#DonorName").val(ui.item.label);
            return false;
        },
        change: function (e, ui) {
            if (!ui.item)
            {
                $("#dialog-form").load("@Url.Action("MinCreate", "Donors")", function () {                        
                    $("#DonorFormName").val(e.target.value);
                    dialog.dialog("open");
                    $("#DonorFormEmail").focus();
                    e.target.value = "";
                });
            }
        }
    });

    var dialog = $("#dialog-form").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        width: 500,
        height: 475,
        dialogClass: "dialogStyle",
        draggable: true,
        resizable: false,
        modal: true,
        hide: { effect: "fade", duration: 1000 },
        title: "New Donor",
        open: function () {
            $(this).closest(".ui-dialog")
            .find(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close")
            .html("<span class='ui-button-icon-primary ui-icon ui-icon-closethick'></span><span class='ui-button-text'>close</span>");
        },
        buttons: {
            Submit: function () {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "@Url.Action("MinCreate", "Donors")",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: $("#DonorForm").serialize(),
                    success: function (data) {
                        if (data.success) {
                            $("#dialog-form").dialog("close");
                            $("#DonorId").val(data.retObject.Id);
                            $("#DonorName").val(data.retObject.Name);
                        }
                        else {
                            $("#dialog-form").html(data);
                        }
                    }
                });
                return false;
            },
        }
    });

    $("#new-donor").click(function () {
        $("#dialog-form").load("@Url.Action("MinCreate", "Donors")", function () {
            dialog.dialog("open")
        });
    });
});
```

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {    
<div class="form-horizontal" id="CreateItem">
    <h4>Item</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Donor.Name, "Donor", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Donor.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @id = "DonorName" } })<a href="#" id="new-donor">New Donor</a>
            @*<input name="donor" class="control-label col-md-2" data-trf-autocomplete="@Url.Action("Autocomplete")" />*@
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.DonorId, new { htmlAttributes = new { @id = "DonorId" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DonorId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <More unimportant form fields... />

    </div>
<div id="dialog-form"></div>
}
```

Finally the code from the controller Donors/MinCreate action:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult MinCreate([Bind(Include = "Id,Name,Email,AddressLine1,City,State,PostalCode,PrimaryPhone")] Donor donor)
{
    try
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Donors.Add(donor);
            db.SaveChanges();
            var result = new { success = true, retObject = donor  };
            return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return Json(new { success = false, retObject = donor });
    }

    return PartialView("_Create", donor);
}
```

I know there might be a lot of useless fluff here, but I'm new to MVC and an exact example is really what I needed.  So, I hope someone out there finds this useful.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery seems like the best way to do this; the Razor ajax helpers always seem kind of clunky to me.

Before getting to that part, take a look at your partial; while you have a div element who's class is set to form-horizontal, you don't actually have a *form* in the partial view. Either use the Razor helper `@using (Html.BeginForm(....))` or add a form with `<form name="this_form" id="this_form" method="post">`

With the form properly set up you can add some Javascript to your partialView and use jQuery to submit the form, then on the success of posting the form you can do a $.get() to update the contents of the parent form or if the post fails, do something else:

```
var stuff = $('#this_form').serialize();
$.post(url_to_your_controller_action, stuff, function (data) {
    // do a $.get() to retrieve updated data then use jQuery to update your parent form

}).fail(function () {

    // do other stuff...
})
```